# efficiently vectorize scipy.stats.beta function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I wanted to fit a curve (with `scipy.curve_fit`) that contains a `beta` distribution in the formula

```
def f(X,a,b):
    # X.shape == (2, 100)
    # X[0] is the column 0 of the matrix X, 
    # the following line doesn't work because a must be a float not an array 
    beta_cdf = beta.cdf([0,0.5,1], a=a*X[0], b=b)) 
    beta_dif = np.diff(beta_cdf)
    return beta_dif*X[1]
```

the problem is that `scipy.stats.beta.cdf` only accepts a float as the `a` parameter, and I need that the shape of the `beta` function depends on the `X[0]` column, I know that I can solve that with a loop, but because I'm using the `scipy.curve_fit` method/solver, I need that the `f(X,a,b)` is evaluated very fast. How can I "vectorize" the `scipy.stats.beta.cdf` so it can receive a NumPy array instead of a float ? or is there a way to "create" a vectorized `beta`?

Thanks !

Comment: `a` needs to be a column vector. This works `beta.cdf([[.0, .5, 1]], a=[[.2],[.1]], b=.2)`.

Comment: `beta` is a class; it's methods like `cdf` use `_boost` code - this is compiled already.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny that was it !!!!! amazing! you can answer the question so I can give you the points :). `a = (a*X[0]).reshape((-1, 1))` did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally turns out that `scipy.stats.beta.cdf` is able to receive a column vector with a list of parameters (thanks @Michael Szczesny for pointing that out).

```
def f(X:np.ndarray, a:float, b:float):
    beta_cdf = beta.cdf([0,0.5,1], 
                        a= a*X[0].reshape((-1, 1)), 
                        b=b)) 
    # where a*X[0].reshape((-1, 1)) its a column wise array = [[1], [2], ..]
    beta_dif = np.diff(beta_cdf)
    return beta_dif*X[1]
```